# want to draw a line by reading coordinates from txt file?

Tags: c#, winforms

First i will explain what i am doing :
I am drawing a line then i am writing the coordinates of the two points of the line in a .txt file using StreamWriter !!
then i open openFiledialog, and read that .txt file saved in which coordinates of the line are safe using streamReader and putting some logic in the same event to draw line but its not drawing the line , its throughing exception all the time , i tried to convert string to int using parse and tryparse but its not helping . Can someone guide me to draw a line by reading coordiantes from text file?? how it can be done?
i am drawing a line using MOuseDown Event

i am using following code

```
     protected void CreateBitmap(int Width, int Height)
    {
        // Create the background bitmap
        BackGroundBitmap = new Bitmap(Width, Height);

        // Set the background bitmap to be the Form's background image
        BackgroundImage = BackGroundBitmap;
    }
string zee1, zee2, zee3, zee4; // Publically declared strings
int m1, n1, m2, n2; // publically declared integers

DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog.
if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
{
    using (StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName, true))
    {
        zee1 = Reader.ReadLine();
        m1 = int.Parse(zee1);

        zee2 = Reader.ReadLine();
        n1 = int.Parse(zee2);

        zee3 = Reader.ReadLine();
        m2 = int.Parse(zee3);

        zee4 = Reader.ReadLine();
        n2 = int.Parse(zee4);

        Graphics gra = Graphics.FromImage(BackGroundBitmap);
        var Teera = new Pen(Color.Black, 5);

        var Nanga1 = new Point(m1, n1);
        var Nanga2 = new Point(m2, n2);
        gra.DrawLine(Teera, Nanga1, Nanga2);
        Teera.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: What exception is it throwing? What values are being returned from the ReadLine method? Are they ints?

Comment: "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: the values of coordinates are in double when thy are saved in .txt file

Comment: Check the value of the value you are trying to parse then. Put a break point on the line and see what it is. Then do you not need to use double.Parse?

Comment: var Nanga1 = new Point(m1, n1) just take int :( no double value. .
i use double type coordinates  value for calculation of distance of a particular line

Comment: OK, it sounds like you might need to parse to a double and round to an int in that case.

Comment: @MichaelB sir then it wont draw the lines at exact coordinates which were saved in .txtfile 
lets suppose 33456.78764 is a coordinate and i just round it it will 33457  and draw line. . that wont serve the purpose of saving coordinates and drawing line

Comment: I wasn't aware you could see the difference between 33456.78764 pixels and 33457 pixels on the computer screen. I would just save them to the text file as an int and then the read function will work.

Comment: its not doing anything after rounding and then converting to int.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so after much testing, I came up with this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ProgramTestDrawLine
{
    class Main_Window : Form
    {
        public Main_Window()
        {
            this.Width = 500;
            this.Height = 500;
            this.Paint += Main_Window_Paint;
        }

        void Main_Window_Paint(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("points.txt");
            string fileContents = sr.ReadLine();
            sr.Close();
            string[] points = fileContents.Split(',');
            Point a = new Point(int.Parse(points[0]), int.Parse(points[1]));
            Point b = new Point(int.Parse(points[2]), int.Parse(points[3]));
            Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
            g.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black,2),a, b);
        }
    }

    class Main_W
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Main_Window form = new Main_Window();
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.Run(form);
        }
    }
}
```

The points.txt file contains the following, single line:

> 15,15,300,300

This, at least for me, works. Try using the Form.Paint event instead of whatever else you are using (I imagine you are using the Form.Load event, which is what I was using originally, and it wasn't drawing the line)

Answer (score 0):

Using PointF & float instead of Point & int would help. Code below.

Edit - Save the image and then set it as background to the form.

```
protected void CreateBitmap(int Width, int Height) 
{ 
    // Create the background bitmap 
    BackGroundBitmap = new Bitmap(Width, Height);           
    // Set the background bitmap to be the Form's background image 
    BackgroundImage = BackGroundBitmap; 
} 


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateBitmap(500, 500);

    string zee1, zee2, zee3, zee4; // Publically declared strings
    float m1, n1, m2, n2; // publically declared integers

    DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog.
    if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
    {
        using (StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName, true))
        {
            zee1 = Reader.ReadLine();
            m1 = float.Parse(zee1);

            zee2 = Reader.ReadLine();
            n1 = float.Parse(zee2);

            zee3 = Reader.ReadLine();
            m2 = float.Parse(zee3);

            zee4 = Reader.ReadLine();
            n2 = float.Parse(zee4);


            Graphics gra = Graphics.FromImage(BackGroundBitmap);
            var Teera = new Pen(Color.Black, 5);

            var Nanga1 = new PointF(m1, n1);
            var Nanga2 = new PointF(m2, n2);
            gra.DrawLine(Teera, Nanga1, Nanga2);
            BackGroundBitmap.Save("result.jpg");
            BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("result.jpg");

            Teera.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is also not working . .:( i am trying it with all the events. .and all the possible combinations but its getting rid of me all the time. doing nothing

Comment: @AnumQazi I tested this on a button click event and it worked fine. How are you initializing BackGroundBitmap, I used a image like `BackGroundBitmap = Image.FromFile("test.jpg");`

Comment: i am working on it from 10 hours nw :( its now not giving any exception but its not drawing the line :(

Comment: Fine, let me see if I can help you. Say me about the BackGroundBitmap initialization, also did you check the result.jpg file.

Comment: protected Bitmap BackGroundBitmap = null; 
protected void CreateBitmap(int Width, int Height)
        {
            // Create the background bitmap
            BackGroundBitmap = new Bitmap(Width, Height);

            // Set the background bitmap to be the Form's background image
            BackgroundImage = BackGroundBitmap;
        }

Comment: i have edited the first coding part of initializing the BackgroundBitmap etc

Answer (score 0):

so finally after so many experiments i have found the answer. 
if someone faces an issue, I have used picturebox and set it disabled . i could have use a panel as well. but picturebox serve the purpose. 
First i am reading from a text file , then these coordinates are passed to DrawLine and thus eventually it draws line. 
Thanks to everyone who commented and answered. It really helped.

here is the code :

```
    private System.Drawing.Graphics g;
    private System.Drawing.Pen pen1 = new System.Drawing.Pen(Color.Blue, 5);
    private void menuItem9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog.
        if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
        {
            using (StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName, true))
            {
                 zee1 = Reader.ReadLine();
                textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(zee1);
                u1 = float.Parse(zee1);

                zee2 = Reader.ReadLine();
                textBox2.Text = zee2;
                v1 = float.Parse(zee2);

                zee3 = Reader.ReadLine();
                textBox3.Text = zee3;
                u2 = float.Parse(zee3);

                zee4 = Reader.ReadLine();
                textBox4.Text = zee4;
                v2 = float.Parse(zee4);

                Reader.Close();


                //BackGroundBitmap.Save("result.jpg"); //test if ok

                pictureBox1.Enabled = true;
                g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
                g.DrawLine(pen1, int.Parse(textBox1.Text), int.Parse(textBox2.Text), int.Parse(textBox3.Text), int.Parse(textBox4.Text));
```